# local storage of images to re-use them again in flash application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, local-storage

I have a flash applcation which has two things
1.Browse for new image component
2.Build scroller image gallery component- has 10 recently uploaded images only

How do I save the new images as and when the user browses it and store it locally and then reuse it again for later sessions (load the images from the saved location and build the scroller again when user visits next time)

Please help me know how to save images locally and then reuse it later as well, more like a history application

Comment: One of the better solutions might be to use shared objects with ByteArrays inside, that hold downloaded images, so you could parse them at shared object load and create your scroller. But, if you need to exactly save an image as a separate file, you need to use FileReference class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go :

This piece of code save images in shared object and restore them when you restart.

[image: Result]

```
package{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    [SWF(width="100",height="800")]
    public class TestSO extends Sprite{

        private var _soFileIndex : SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("fileIndex");
        private var _addBtn : Sprite = new Sprite;
        private var _fr : FileReference = new FileReference;

        public function TestSO(){
            // Add a button
            var tf : TextField = new TextField;
            tf.text = "Add image";
            tf.width = 100;
            tf.height = 20;
            tf.selectable = false;
            _addBtn.addChild(tf);
            _addBtn.graphics.beginFill(0xDDDDDD);
            _addBtn.graphics.drawRect(0,0,_addBtn.width, _addBtn.height);
            _addBtn.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(_addBtn);

            // If file index is empty
            if(!_soFileIndex.data.index)
                _soFileIndex.data.index = [];
            else{
                // Display stored images
                for each(var fileName : String in _soFileIndex.data.index)
                    displayImage(fileName, SharedObject.getLocal(fileName).data.bytes)
            }

            // Listeners
            _addBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAddClick);
            _fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
            _fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
        }

        // Ask for a file
        private function onAddClick(e : Event) : void{
            _fr.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png")]);
        }

        // open file
        private function onFileSelected(e : Event) : void{
            _fr.load();
        }

        // save file
        private function onFileLoaded(e : Event) : void{

            var fileName : String = _fr.name.split(" ").join("_");
            // Save a reference to filename
            if(_soFileIndex.data.index.indexOf(fileName) == -1)
                _soFileIndex.data.index.push(fileName);
            else return;


            var fileSo : SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(fileName);
            fileSo.data.bytes = _fr.data;
            fileSo.flush();

            displayImage(fileName, _fr.data);
        }

        // Display an image
        private function displayImage(name : String, data : ByteArray):void{
            var item : Sprite = new Sprite;

            // Load image
            var imgLoader : Loader = new Loader;
            imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onImageLoaded);
            imgLoader.loadBytes(data);
            item.addChild(imgLoader);

            var label : TextField = new TextField;
            label.text = name;
            label.y = 100;
            label.height = 20;
            item.addChild(label);

            item.y = height;
            addChild(item);
        }

        // Resize image when loaded
        private function onImageLoaded(e : Event) : void{
            e.target.content.width = e.target.content.height = 100;
            e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onImageLoaded);
        }
    }
}
```